# Am I doing this right? VueX and Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Can someone please help me? I actually don't understand how to initiate `localForage` (`getItem` and `setItem`) in VueX. I have an array on component side, and need to copy it to indexedDB by VueX.

So I have `mounted()` and `watch` on the component and trying to activate them by using actions on VueX. Is this possible?

Here is the code on VueX:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5wMj.png)

and here component side:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcoIN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Fdz.png)

```js
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        totalTvCount: 10, // The TV inventory
        notes: []

    },

    getters: {
        totalTvCount: state => state.totalTvCount,// Here we will create a getter
        notes: state => state.notes
    },

    mutations: {
       incTv(state, amount){
           state.totalTvCount += amount
       } // Here we will create Jenny
    },

    actions: {
        inc(context, amount) {
            context.commit('incTv', amount)
        },  // Here we will create Larry
        setItems(){
            localStorage.setItem("notes")
        },
        getItems(){
            localStorage.getItem("notes").then(data => {
                this.state.notes = data
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Roman: could you please explain what's going wrong with your code as it stands now? Also, are you using localForage, the plugin, or LocalStorage directly?

Comment: i was installed it by npm, here is whole code

Comment: Could you replace the screen shots of code with the actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a mutation for setting the notes

```
setNotes(state, notes) {
    state.notes = notes
 }
```

then commit the mutation from your action:

```
getItems({commit}) {
    localStorage.getItem("notes")
    .then(data => commit('setNotes', data) )
 }
```